# Access DLL From VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dll, header-files, solution

The answer to my question may already be out there, but I am having no success synthesizing the data into a coherent solution.  Your advice is appreciated.

I am writing a "User Control" application using Visual Basic (.NET 3.5) and Visual Studio 2012.  I have been given a DLL file which contains functionality that I must access.  Additionally, I have been given corresponding .LIB and .H files, which I am told will be necessary to properly make use of the DLL.  I believe the DLL was written in C.

I have also been provided with some older VB code which is said to make use of the DLL's functions one that DLL is "included" (or something) in the project.  As you can probably tell, my grasp on this is tenuous at best.  Here is the VB code:

```
Private Declare Function SF_AddToCommandQueue Lib "SFrmUt80.dll" Alias "_SF_AddToCommandQueue@8" _
    (ByVal CmdCode As Integer, ByVal strParam As String) As Boolean

Private Declare Function SF_FlushCommandQueue Lib "SFrmUt80.dll" Alias "_SF_FlushCommandQueue@4" _
    (ByVal strWindowTitle As String) As Boolean

Private Declare Function SF_GetUserName Lib "SFrmUt80.dll" Alias "_SF_GetUserName@8" _
    (ByVal strBuffer As String, ByVal BufferSize As Integer) As Integer

Private Declare Function SF_GetUserID Lib "SFrmUt80.dll" Alias "_SF_GetUserID@0" _
    () As Integer

Private Declare Function SF_GetCmdType Lib "SFrmUt80.dll" Alias "_SF_GetCmdType@0" _
    () As Integer

Private Declare Function SF_GetCmdFilename Lib "SFrmUt80.dll" Alias "_SF_GetCmdFilename@8" _
    (ByVal strBuffer As String, ByVal BufferSize As Integer) As Integer

Private Declare Function SF_GetRegisteredMsg Lib "SFrmUt80.dll" Alias "_SF_GetRegisteredMsg@0" _
    () As Integer
```

Hoping this is not too vague, I am wondering how I go about integrating this DLL file into my solution, so that I may make use of its functionality in VB .NET.

Your wisdom is very much appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.H`-files won't be of much use to you, as you don't use them in the managed environment. You would actually just include the `DLL`s into your solution (i.e. add them to the project in the `Solution-Explorer`).
VS does the rest for you, all you need to do is, as you already did, declare the functions from the library in your source-code and call the functions.

On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26thfadc.aspx) there is an article on this.

Comment: The OP is clearly not talking about a COM component or .NET assembly but a C API library. As such, the library doesn’t need to be included / managed in the solution. You just declare the functions.

Comment: And how do you link to the DLL if the project doesn't know it exists?

Comment: You don’t. The linking is done at runtime, and not by the project but by WinAPI functions (`LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`). The project only needs to know about the DLL file for deployment purposes if it’s supposed to be copied during the process. However, as far as the solution is concerned it’s just another resource file.

Comment: That is what I am talking about. You'll need to add it to the managed project, so the Solution knows it's there.

Comment: Again, no; not in general. That entirely depends on how your project and the other DLL is deployed. Often they are deployed separately (either because it’s already installed, think WinAPI DLL, or because it’s installed by a separate installation routine from another product).

Comment: In that particular case I agree! But the question is: is it?

Comment: This DLL file will need to be distributed along with my application to each machine on which it is installed.  It will be located in the same directory as my application (which itself is a DLL, in the end).  When I try to do Add Reference, VS throws and error ("... please make sure it is a valid assembly or COM component.").  I am able to add the file itself to the solution explorer pane without any drama, but remain confused on how to proceed from there.  Do I put the code I pasted above into its own class and call the functions as shared or instance members or something?  Baby steps here :-)

Comment: Got it!  Just copied that VB code directly into the user control class I was writing, and all was right.  Thank you for the help, both of you.